# Problem with running a wire from the AIY shield to the microphone and speaker

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, google-aiy

I'm building a project for a museum in which participants can record their own audio descriptions of the art. I'm using the voicekit 1 and added GPIO functionality for 2 extra buttons.
I’m running into a problem though; the only way for the speaker to work is by unplugging the microphone.
If i plug the microphone, the speaker stops working!
I added 2 buttons on the servo pins 0 and 1 (using GPIO 4 and 17 with the GPIO library) and those buttons work fine.

The voicekit button also works fine and its connected as it comes.
I’m sure the problem is not with the code, cause i’ve made various tests (Without the extra buttons, with the base program)

I’m running 2ft wire from the RPI to the 2 extra buttons, the mic and the speaker, all of which is in an enclosure (Like an old telephone)
Any thoughts? might it be an electrical issue? (I’ve also tested conductivity on all wires and it’s zero resistance)

I'm running a 2 ft. wire from the AIY shield to a "telephone" like device, for people to interact with.
The speaker stopped working, and obly works if i unplug the microphone.